# Can I climb all the hills in Macau?

Tags: hiking, macau

Most tourists in Macau get up to Guia hill with the lighthouse and fortress and maybe the Monte Fort right next to the ruins of the church of St. Paul, but Macau has many other green hills.

I'm currently in Macau for a while and already accidently stumbled upon several other lovely public parks with a hill:
Luis de Camoes Grotto and Gardens, Mong Ha Hill Municipal Park, Jardim Da Montanha Russa, Penha Hill and Taipa Grande.

I decided I want to hike up all the hills in Macau, but would like to find out first whether that's actually possible. The hills I haven't been to yet are:

On Macau island there is Barra Hill and also a hill on Ilha Verde. On the south Island there are Taipa Pequena, Alto de Coloane plus several peaks in the same region. I may even miss some, the online maps I have a not that great.

Comment: Have you seen this page here? http://www.iacm.gov.mo/e/facility/introduction/trails/

Comment: Yes, I've seen that and I will do all those and the trails cover most of the hills but not all. Thanks.

Comment: Can you comment which ones you are missing? While I think that hardly any of them are "locked up", it might help if you can narrow down the selection as much as possible, best would be with google maps locations.

Comment: The second paragraph has the ones I've done, the last paragraph the ones I haven't

Comment: Ah, I was not clear if the second paragraph might contain some that are covered on the government site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strict answer is no! There are certain hills that are not accessible because there are no public paths leading to the top.

However considering each hill has one or more 'peaks', at least one peak is accessible on each hill.

I created a [page](http://peter.hahndorf.eu/trip/2014/macauhills.html) which lists all the hills and has some information about their accessibility.